# Kick member from voice chat (Кикнуть из голосового канала)

Tags: discord.py

```
@bot.command()
async def kick():
    member_id = ###
    guild_id = ###
    guild = bot.get_guild(guild_id)
    member: Member = guild.get_member(member_id)
    
    await member.move_to(None)
```

Мне нужна команда, которую я буду писать на своём личном сервере и она будет кикать из голосового канала чела на другом сервере. Я просто не знаю как сделать что бы оно считало другой сервер, а не тот на котором я пишу команду.

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Comment: У вас уже есть переменная `guild_id` и ниже вы получаете объект нужного сервера `guild`. Но при этом участника все равно берете из сервера, который лежит в контексте

Comment: @denisnumb, какой командой брать участника из сервера, который в guild_id?

Comment: Участника сервера нужно брать не из `guild_id`. Используя `guild_id` вы получаете объект сервера `guild = bot.get_guild(guild_id)`, а вот из `guild` уже можно взять участника, так же как вы это делаете в коде из вашего вопроса — `guild.get_member(member_id)`

Comment: @denisnumb используя guild в get_member, выходит ошибка, которая требует в @bot.command() минимум 0 параметров :)

Comment: @BlackBlock [`get_member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild.get_member) принимает один позиционный параметр — id участника, там не может быть 0, скорее всего что-то не так делаете

Comment: @denisnumb Вот что у меня получается:


 @bot.command()
async def kick():
    member_id = #Айди
    guild_id = #Айди
    member: Member = guild.get_member(member_id)
    guild = bot.get_guild(guild_id)

    await member.move_to(None)

Comment: Ну так логично, вы же сначала пытаетесь от `guild` получить участника, а только потом получаете объект сервера

Comment: @denisnumb Ну если я поставлю guild = bot.get_guild(guild_id) перед member: Member = guild.get_member(member_id), то ничего не изменится

Comment: Тогда 1. Проверьте, включены и выданы ли [intents](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/discord-py.md#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C); 2. Убедитесь, что оба `id` точно правильные; 3. Убедитесь, что бот находится в списке участников сервера с идентификатором `guild_id`; И отправьте текст ошибки

Comment: @denisnumb Текст ошибки:
_Exception has occurred: TypeError
Command signature requires at least 0 parameter(s)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\bot.py", line 50, in <module>
    @bot.command()
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Command signature requires at least 0 parameter(s)_

Comment: Ошибка не в строке из вопроса, а чем-то другом

Comment: @denisnumb Вот более подробно: **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...", line 235, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\...", line 54, in kick
    member: Member = guild.get_member(member_id)
                     ^^^^^**

Comment: **UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'guild' where it is not associated with a value

  File "C:\...", line 1029, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'guild' where it is not associated with a value**

Comment: но все права intents есть

Comment: ну, ошибка буквально означает, что вы пытаетесь использовать локальную переменную `guild`, у которой нет значения (скорее всего используете перед тем, как проинициализировать `guild`, получив объект сервера)

Comment: @denisnumb Изменил содержимое вопроса, на то, что у меня сейчас. Подскажите, что изменить

Comment: `ctx` в аргументы обработчика команды верните. Это обязательный аргумент для команд, помеченных декоратором `@bot.command()`

Comment: Наконец то работает, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def kick(ctx, member_id: int, guild_id: int):
    guild = bot.get_guild(guild_id)
    
    if guild:
        member = await guild.fetch_member(member_id)
        if member:
            if member.voice:
                await member.edit(voice_channel=None)
                await ctx.send(f'{member.display_name} был кикнут из голосового канала на сервере {guild.name}.')
            else:
                await ctx.send(f'{member.display_name} не находится в голосовом канале на сервере {guild.name}.')
        else:
            await ctx.send('Указанный участник не найден на сервере.')
    else:
        await ctx.send('Указанный сервер не найден.')
```

Напишите !kick <member_id> <guild_id>, все!